Can complexity in philosophy be approximated using computer science concepts?
I was wondering about the usefulness of approximating the complexity of theories using computer science concepts.
Now of course, theories are not computer science models. But when judging the complexity of a theory, one creates a mental model anyways, and if we’re going to try to approximate the complexity of a theory using a model, why not use a computer science model instead of your own?
For example, take the Cartesian demon experiment. An All Powerful Demon who exists solely for the purpose of creating an illusion of the world seems more intuitively complex than the world just actually being real. The way that the world looks to us would be the same assuming each theory, thus analyzing the complexity of each theory seems to play an important role in helping us decide which one is more likely to be true.
Now, expanding on this intuition may be difficult, and many may not even share this intuition. But when one imagines the world as a computer program, or perhaps imagines a video game that can be coded to mock reality, it seems pretty obvious and more clear that coding up an all powerful demon who creates this world is much, much, more complex than simply coding the world itself. The amount of code that would have to be written would be much larger.
When phrased in these terms, the complexity of a certain theory seems to become more clear. Is there a term for this? Have philosophers discussed this?

Occam's razor: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor Suppose an event has two possible explanations. The explanation that requires the fewest assumptions is usually correct. Another way of saying it is that the more assumptions you have to make, the more unlikely an explanation. Occam's razor applies especially in the philosophy of science, but also appears in everyday life.

Algorithmic complexity...
